# How to remove a character from some rows in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a large `DataFrame` that I need to clean, as a sample please look at this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4','Suzuki'],
        'Price': ['22000.T','25000.T','27000','.TPX','.NKM1']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

print (df)
```

I want to remove `'.T'` from the end of the words, and only `'.'` from the beginning of the rows that contain the.

by the following line of code, I could remove the `'.T'`

```
df['Price'].replace('.T', '', regex=True)
```

but it also removed the `'T'` from the `'.TPX'`

any advice on this is appreciated.

```
0    22000
1    25000
2    27000
3       PX
4    .NKM1
Name: Price, dtype: object
```

Also for removing the `'.'` when I add this line

```
f['Price'].replace('.', '', regex=True)
```

I get a different dataframe as what I expected

```
0    
1    
2    
3    
4    
Name: Price, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way would be to use **[`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)** and evaluate your conditions using [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [`str.endswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html):

```
import numpy as np

p = df['Price'].str
df['Price'] = np.where(p.startswith('.'),p.replace('.','',regex=True),
                         np.where(p.endswith('.T'),p.replace('.T','',regex=True),p))
```

This will check whether `df['Price']` starts with a `.` or ends with a `.T` and replace them.

```
            Brand  Price
0     Honda Civic  22000
1  Toyota Corolla  25000
2      Ford Focus  27000
3         Audi A4    TPX
4          Suzuki   NKM1
```

Answer (score 6):

#### `Series.str.replace`

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.replace(r'^(?:\.)?(.*?)(?:\.T)?$', r'\g<1>')
```

#### `Series.str.extract`

```
df['Price'] = df['Price'].str.extract(r'^(?:\.)?(.*?)(?:\.T)?$', expand=False)
```

---

```
            Brand  Price
0     Honda Civic  22000
1  Toyota Corolla  25000
2      Ford Focus  27000
3         Audi A4    TPX
4          Suzuki   NKM1
```

**Regex details:**

- `^` : Assert position at the start of line
- `(?:\.)` : Non capturing group which matches the character `.`
- `?` : Matches the previous non capturing group zero or one time
- `(.*?)` : Capturing group which matches any character except line terminators zero or more times but as few times as possible (`lazy match`)
- `(?:\.T)` : Non capturing group which matches `.T`
- `?` : Matches the previous non capturing group zero or one time
- `$` : Asserts position at the end of the line

See the [`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/2urKpc/1)

Comment: @anky Because it would also remove unwanted characters at the start and end..Consider the imaginary word  `ABCDDTTT.T` so using `.rstrip(.T)` would result in `ABCDD` that means it would also remove extra `T's` at the end which might be undesirable...Although if that's not a problem in the dataset then we can definitely use `rstrip.`

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to what you want with anchors and what's called a positive lookbehind.

`df['Price'].replace('(?<=.)\.T$', '', regex=True)`

With regular expressions, there's special characters that have added functionality. Here, the '$' means ends with. So if you want to just affect stings that end in '.T' you want to add that to the end. The part of the expression that is the lookbehind is '(?<=.)'. The parentheses signify a group.

I don't really know how to explain it other than it's kind of similar to how CSS classes work, which really isn't that great of an example.

The '?<=.' is the actual parameters for the lookbehind, it tells the regex engine to match any character ( the '.' ) before the match that exists outside the group ( '.T' ).

To replace the words starting with '.' is very simple. It's just the opposite anchor,

`df['Price'].replace('^\.', '', regex=True)`

https://regex101.com/ is a great website to help build your regexes. It will also explain what your regex does.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
In [178]: import numpy as np

In [179]: conds = [df.Price.str.endswith('.T'), df.Price.str.startswith('.')]
In [182]: choices = [df.Price.str.replace('.T', '', regex=True), df.Price.str.replace('.', '', regex=True)]

In [189]: df.Price = np.select(conds, choices, default=df.Price)

In [190]: df
Out[190]: 
            Brand  Price
0     Honda Civic  22000
1  Toyota Corolla  25000
2      Ford Focus  27000
3         Audi A4    TPX
4          Suzuki   NKM1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can match either a dot at the start of the string, or match `.T` at the end. Then use an empty string in the replacement.

```
\A\.|\.T\Z
```

For example

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4','Suzuki'],
        'Price': ['22000.T','25000.T','27000','.TPX','.NKM1']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])
df['Price'] = df['Price'].replace(r"\A\.|\.T\Z", "", regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output

```
            Brand  Price
0     Honda Civic  22000
1  Toyota Corolla  25000
2      Ford Focus  27000
3         Audi A4    TPX
4          Suzuki   NKM1
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to explain why you got that result. This is because `.` has special meaning when used in pattern, [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) list of special characters starts with

> `.` (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a
> newline. If the `DOTALL` flag has been specified, this matches any
> character including a newline.

So when you mean *literal* `.` you need to escape it, consider following example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["3.45"]})
df["unescaped"] = df.col1.replace(r'.','X',regex=True)
df["escaped"] = df.col1.replace(r'\.','X',regex=True)
print(df)
```

output

```
   col1 unescaped escaped
0  3.45      XXXX    3X45
```

Note that I used so called raw-string here, which allows more readable form of escaping characters with special meaning in pattern (without raw-string I would have to write `'\\.'`, consult `re` docs for more information). If you struggle with regular expression pattern I suggest using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to get its explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```py
>>> df['Price'].str.replace(r'^\.|\.T$', '', regex=True)
0    22000
1    25000
2    27000
3      TPX
4     NKM1
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/PHapP0/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  T                        'T'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```